# Angular deploy to Azure static web apps not working

Tags: angular, azure, github-actions, azure-static-web-app

I'm trying to deploy an angular app to azure static web apps.

```
node version = 16.18.1
npm version = 8.8.0
```

Azure uses gitub actions to build and deploy the code.

When I push the code, github actions starts building the code and fails with this error:

```
Using Node version: 
v16.20.2

Using Npm version:
8.19.4

Running 'npm install'...

npm ERR! Invalid version
```

How can I fix this? How can I set npm version?

**Edit:**

On my local, I have to run:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Looks like it is failing because of this. Any solution to this?

Comment: Haven't used neither Azure Static Web Apps nor Github Actions yet but I'm guessing it might have something to do with Node 16 not being supported because it's end-of-life? See [Github NodeJS Release](https://github.com/nodejs/Release#end-of-life-releases)

Comment: Just saw the edit to your question. `--legacy-peer-deps` makes `npm` ignore inconsistent peer dependencies, also see [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/config#legacy-peer-deps).

Maybe installed package versions are inconsistent to some peer dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I tried to implement the same in my environment, got the same error.

- Installed `"@angular/core": "^7.0.0"` as **Peer dependency** in local.

**Package.json:**

```json
{
  "name": "peerangularapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~5.0.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.0"
  }
}
```

[image]

In my case, I figured out that I was getting the error because I had `@angular/core` dependency in both dependencies and peer dependencies section with different versions in `package.json`.

- To resolve this, I had to remove `@angular/core` in dependencies section and changed the version of `@angular/core` to `16.0.0` in peer dependencies.

(or)

- Remove peer dependencies and add to dependencies in `package.json`, later those `dependencies` can be added manually to `peer dependencies`:

**Able to deploy the Angular application to static web app successfully:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Running the deployed application:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pravallika, upgrading angular helped in running npm install cleanly